# plt.show() does not print plt.plot only plt.scatter

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

So, for the following code no graph is printed in jupyter notebook. If I use plt.scatter then it does produce graph. Any suggestions what could be wrong? Can it be caused by the data?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def calc_gauss(df, index):

    x=df.iloc[[index]]
    mean = df.apply(lambda x: x.mean(), axis=1)
    mu=mean.iloc[[index]]
    std = df.std(axis=1)
    sig=std.iloc[[index]]

    dens = norm.pdf(x,mu,sig)

    # build the plot
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9,6))
    plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')
    ax.plot(x, dens)
    return plt.show()

calc_gauss(df_distance, 339)
```

Comment: instead of `return plt.show()` just do `plt.show()`. That should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```py
return plt.show()
```

use

```py
fig.show()
```

If you want the picture to show in the notebook, use `%matplotlib inline` in a cell evaluated before the `show` command

**Note** the problem was that the arrays were shape (1,24). plot likes only 1D arrays. Replacing `ax.plot(x, dens)` with `ax.plot(x.reshape(-1), dens.reshape(-1))` solved the issue.

Comment: Hi, it doesn’t seem to do anything.

Comment: Can you print the shape and values of `x` and `dens`?

Comment: That's the problem. `plot` likes only 1D arrays. Replace `ax.plot(x, dens)` with `ax.plot(x.reshape(-1), dens.reshape(-1))`